# How to add a like to something but only once using local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, addeventlistener

I'm working with an API and i need to display movies and like them but i need to like them once. I tried to add a boolean and I had something like this:

```
let beenLiked = false;

const movieLike = document.getElementById("likeButton")
movieLike.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("ok like")
    axios.patch(`myUrl`)
    beenLiked = true
}, true)
```

the problem is when I like a movie, i can't like another one because of my boolean, how can I modify it to solve my problem?

Comment: It depends on how you want to keep track of likes. 
Do you have a user system?
If not, do you track IP's?
Like what is the constraint for not liking more than once.
Do you have multiple people?
Then you should definetely track it in your dataBase or wherever you have the likes saved and save people there in an array.
Once you call the api check if the requestor already liked this movie by looking for a match in your array. Then refuse the action if it was already liked.
Or you could disable the eventListener (which though will be reactivated on page reloading :/)

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum the problem is that we don't have any database and we just have as instructions to be able to like a movie, store this like by any means to make the movie unlikable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the name of the movie that is supposed to be liked (I don't have your html file to do it for you), you can track the names and do it like this:

```js
let beenLiked = []

const movieLike = document.getElementById("likeButton")
movieLike.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const movie = "The Movie" // Get the movie name or id which has to be liked
    if(beenLiked.indexOf(movie) === -1){
        console.log("ok like")
        axios.patch(`myUrl`)
        beenLiked.push(movie)
        return true
    }
    console.log("Already liked once")
    return false
})
```

here the simplified version without html:

```js
let beenLiked = []

function a() {
  const movie = "The Movie" // Get the movie the likeButton is attached to
  if (beenLiked.indexOf(movie) === -1) {
    beenLiked.push(movie)
    return true
  }
  return false
}
console.log(a())
console.log(a())
```

Comment: so i tried to run your code and after some little modifications i run it and i got a console error saying this: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'indexOf') at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>

Comment: at school your code was working great but now that I'm at home i doesn't work anymore and i don'tknow why